# Boost SSL with Visual Studio 2010 and OpenSSL

Tags: visual-studio-2010, boost, openssl

I'm trying to compile the Boost 1.47 ASIO SSL server and client examples. I can sucessfully incorporate Boost into my project, but I cannot incorporate OpenSSL. When I try to add it I get the errors:

```
1>SSLServer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ERR_reason_error_string referenced in function "public: virtual class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall boost::asio::error::detail::ssl_category::message(int)const " (?message@ssl_category@detail@error@asio@boost@@UBE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H@Z)
1>SSLServer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _CRYPTO_set_id_callback referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::asio::ssl::detail::openssl_init_base::do_init::do_init(void)" (??0do_init@openssl_init_base@detail@ssl@asio@boost@@QAE@XZ)
1>SSLServer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _CRYPTO_set_locking_callback referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::asio::ssl::detail::openssl_init_base::do_init::do_init(void)" (??0do_init@openssl_init_base@detail@ssl@asio@boost@@QAE@XZ)
1>SSLServer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _CRYPTO_num_locks referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::asio::ssl::detail::openssl_init_base::do_init::do_init(void)" (??0do_init@openssl_init_base@detail@ssl@asio@boost@@QAE@XZ)
1>SSLServer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_load_error_strings referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::asio::ssl::detail::openssl_init_base::do_init::do_init(void)" (??0do_init@openssl_init_base@detail@ssl@asio@boost@@QAE@XZ)
1>SSLServer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_library_init referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::asio::ssl::detail::openssl_init_base::do_init::do_init(void)" (??0do_init@openssl_init_base@detail@ssl@asio@boost@@QAE@XZ)
1>SSLServer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ENGINE_cleanup referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::asio::ssl::detail::openssl_init_base::do_init::~do_init(void)" (??1do_init@openssl_init_base@detail@ssl@asio@boost@@QAE@XZ)
1>SSLServer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _CONF_modules_unload referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::asio::ssl::detail::openssl_init_base::do_init::~do_init(void)" (??1do_init@openssl_init_base@detail@ssl@asio@boost@@QAE@XZ)
1>SSLServer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _CRYPTO_cleanup_all_ex_data referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::asio::ssl::detail::openssl_init_base::do_init::~do_init(void)" (??1do_init@openssl_init_base@detail@ssl@asio@boost@@QAE@XZ)
1>SSLServer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _EVP_cleanup referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::asio::ssl::detail::openssl_init_base::do_init::~do_init(void)" (??1do_init@openssl_init_base@detail@ssl@asio@boost@@QAE@XZ)
1>SSLServer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ERR_remove_state referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::asio::ssl::detail::openssl_init_base::do_init::~do_init(void)" (??1do_init@openssl_init_base@detail@ssl@asio@boost@@QAE@XZ)
1>SSLServer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ERR_free_strings referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::asio::ssl::detail::openssl_init_base::do_init::~do_init(void)" (??1do_init@openssl_init_base@detail@ssl@asio@boost@@QAE@XZ)
1>C:\Users\Epicism\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SSLServer\Debug\SSLServer.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 12 unresolved externals
1>
1>Build FAILED.
```

I have tried adding the directory C:\OpenSSL-Win32\lib\, C:\OpenSSL-Win32\lib\VC\, C:\OpenSSL-Win32\lib\VC\static, C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin, C:\OpenSSL-Win32\include to Project->General Properties->Linker->Additional Library Directories using the openssl pre-compiled libraries (http://www.openssl.org/related/binaries.html). I have also tried compiling OpenSSL myself with the same errors. I'm really at a loss, I have tried everything I have searched Google about a thousand times, tried IRC, every combination of directories I can think of...

My setup is:
Windows 7 64-bit
Windows Visual Studio 2010 64 bit
Boost 1.47
OpenSSL 1.0.0E and G
C/C++ Additional Include Directories: C:\Program Files (x86)\boost\boost_1_47;C:\openssl\include\;C:\OpenSSL-Win32\lib;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)
Project->General Properties->Linker->Additional Library Directories: C:\Program Files (x86)\boost\boost_1_47\lib;C:\openssl\lib;C:\openssl;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)
    - I've tried adding every directory to this property as well....

Right now I'm just trying to compile the following in a VS C++ console project:

// SSLServer.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: YES me too I have this problem as welll

Comment: I have this problem as well.  Did anyone manage to figure it out?  Please post back if you do.  Tried Fraser's suggestion below, but still have the problem.

Answer (score 10):

Looks like you're using the 32-bit version of OpenSSL on a 64-bit machine.

Try downloading the 64-bit version (Win64 OpenSSL v1.0.0g) from http://www.slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

After that's installed (if you use default paths), you should have a `C:\OpenSSL-Win64` folder.

You should add:

- `C:\OpenSSL-Win64\include` to your Additional Include Directories
- `C:\OpenSSL-Win64\lib\VC\static` or `C:\OpenSSL-Win64\lib\VC` to your Additional Library Directories depending on whether you want the static libs or the dlls respectively
- `libeay32<XXX>.lib` and `ssleay32<XXX>.lib` to Additional Dependencies where `<XXX>` matches whatever setting you have for `[C/C++]->[Code Generation]->[Runtime Library]`

Comment: How do you get this working with Visual Studio 2015 and Boost.Build, from the command line (e.g. through a Jamfile?)

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get your little program above to build by linking with the 32-bit version of the Boost library along with the 32-bit version of OpenSSL.  You will also need the 32-bit version of the [redistributables](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) as well.  The bug is present in Boost version 1.51 and 1.52, which are the only versions I tested.

I believe there is a bug in the 64-bit version of the ASIO library.  Although, it is possible that it is some sort of configuration problem that has affected many others.  I have submitted a Boost bug report about the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I met with the similar issue(VS2010)， solved methods:

1)Properties->C/C++ ->general->additional include Directories:  yourpath\boost_1_58_0\boost_1_58_0 (I use 1.58.0 version)

2)Properties->Linker ->general->additional library directories:
yourpath\boost_1_58_0\boost_1_58_0\stage\lib

3)Properties->Linker ->Input ->additional Dependencies:
libeay32.lib
ssleay32.lib

These two .lib files are copied from openssl install directory.