# Unresolved external Symbol OpenSSL Libraries C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, openssl

I'm trying to compile my program with Visual Studio 2013 C++,

I have no errors until I compile.

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _EVP_DecryptUpdate
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _EVP_DecryptInit
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _EVP_DecryptFinal
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _EVP_aes_128_cbc
```

I'm using stock OpenSSL Libraries. I've successfully linked them to the openssl folder.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate.I just need some assistance as I'm lost and I don't know what to do.. :l

Comment: That question has numerous detailed answers as to the multiple sources of this type of error (missing symbols). I think the help I can offer is to work through every answer - it is tedious but that goes part in parcel with the problem you have.

Comment: Have you ever linked with an external library using VS 2013 C++ before? In other words is this some unusual problem and you know what you are doing, or are you just looking for someone to explain how to do linking with VS 2013 C++?

Comment: The file was given to me by a friend. He gave me instructions and I've followed, I don't want to damage the file. But I'll try things and get back to you.

Comment: @john I know how to link a library, and I've done that.

Comment: I cant think of anything you could do that would damage the file. What you should do is say what the instructions you followed are. Anyone trying to help is a bit in the dark at the moment.

Comment: Look at [How to use OpenSSL with Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11383942/how-to-use-openssl-with-visual-studio)

Comment: I'm trying everything you guys are doing.

Comment: Did your friend build them in 32 or 64 bit mode, are you building in the same mode?

Comment: 32 bit, how do I check?

Comment: Put the linker into verbose mode `/VERBOSE:Lib` and inspect the search path. You'll note that it's missing the openssl lib.

Answer (score 11):

Taken from: [using OpenSSL in Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127824/using-openssl-in-visual-studio-2012)

**UPDATE**

This question helped me also in finding the solution. Boost SSL with Visual Studio 2010 and OpenSSL

The steps required to use the openSSL lib with VS2012:

- download and install a version (I have 64bit OS, however I installed
  32bit openssl) from http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html.
- New project in VS, then Configuration
  Properties/C/C++/General/Additional Include Directories: openssl
  include folder (C:\OpenSSL-Win32\include)
- Linker/General/Additional Library Directiories: C:\OpenSSL-Win32\lib
- Linker/Input/Additional Dependencies :
- libeay32.lib libeay32MTd.lib libeay32MT.lib libeay32MDd.lib
  libeay32MD.lib ssleay32.lib ssleay32MTd.lib ssleay32MT.lib
  ssleay32MDd.lib ssleay32MD.lib

(It was written that I need to only add that one which matches with C/C++/Code Generation/Runtime Library, but It works me this way.)

Copy theese files into current VS folder /VC/lib

**This is what helped me**

Comment: You can formally accept your own answer I think.