# Implementing TLS1.2 Connection in c++ using openssl 1.0.2d with visual studio 2010 on windows 7 32bit

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

i saw the process that how to use openssl in visual studio here
[using OpenSSL in Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127824/using-openssl-in-visual-studio-2012)
now when i compile the code it get compiled with success but while running pop up comes with "**the ordinal 3906 could not be located in the dynamic link library LIBEAY32.dll**"

Answer (score 0):

The SSL DLL(s) is/are not getting loaded at runtime. Need to put it/them in a folder the program will search.