# fatal error LNK1120: 19 unresolved externals

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cassandra, boost-asio

I have been trying to communicate with my cassandra database with this [demo code](https://github.com/datastax/cpp-driver) from Cassandra's cpp-driver. I am using Visual Studio Express 2013 I have been blocked with the following errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Test_Boost, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  main.cpp`
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cql::cql_initialize(void)" (?cql_initialize@cql@@YAXXZ) referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class boost::shared_ptr<class cql::cql_builder_t> __cdecl cql::cql_cluster_t::builder(void)" (?builder@cql_cluster_t@cql@@SA?AV?$shared_ptr@Vcql_builder_t@cql@@@boost@@XZ) referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _sk_new_null referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::asio::ssl::detail::openssl_init_base::do_init::do_init(void)" (??0do_init@openssl_init_base@detail@ssl@asio@boost@@QAE@XZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _sk_free referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::asio::ssl::detail::openssl_init_base::do_init::~do_init(void)" (??1do_init@openssl_init_base@detail@ssl@asio@boost@@QAE@XZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _CRYPTO_cleanup_all_ex_data referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::asio::ssl::detail::openssl_init_base::do_init::~do_init(void)" (??1do_init@openssl_init_base@detail@ssl@asio@boost@@QAE@XZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _CRYPTO_num_locks referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::asio::ssl::detail::openssl_init_base::do_init::do_init(void)" (??0do_init@openssl_init_base@detail@ssl@asio@boost@@QAE@XZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _CRYPTO_set_locking_callback referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::asio::ssl::detail::openssl_init_base::do_init::do_init(void)" (??0do_init@openssl_init_base@detail@ssl@asio@boost@@QAE@XZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _CRYPTO_set_id_callback referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::asio::ssl::detail::openssl_init_base::do_init::do_init(void)" (??0do_init@openssl_init_base@detail@ssl@asio@boost@@QAE@XZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _CONF_modules_unload referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::asio::ssl::detail::openssl_init_base::do_init::~do_init(void)" (??1do_init@openssl_init_base@detail@ssl@asio@boost@@QAE@XZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::asio::ssl::detail::openssl_init_base::do_init::do_init(void)" (??0do_init@openssl_init_base@detail@ssl@asio@boost@@QAE@XZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _EVP_cleanup referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::asio::ssl::detail::openssl_init_base::do_init::~do_init(void)" (??1do_init@openssl_init_base@detail@ssl@asio@boost@@QAE@XZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_load_error_strings referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::asio::ssl::detail::openssl_init_base::do_init::do_init(void)" (??0do_init@openssl_init_base@detail@ssl@asio@boost@@QAE@XZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_library_init referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::asio::ssl::detail::openssl_init_base::do_init::do_init(void)" (??0do_init@openssl_init_base@detail@ssl@asio@boost@@QAE@XZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ERR_reason_error_string referenced in function "public: virtual class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall boost::asio::error::detail::ssl_category::message(int)const " (?message@ssl_category@detail@error@asio@boost@@UBE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ERR_free_strings referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::asio::ssl::detail::openssl_init_base::do_init::~do_init(void)" (??1do_init@openssl_init_base@detail@ssl@asio@boost@@QAE@XZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ERR_remove_state referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::asio::ssl::detail::openssl_init_base::do_init::~do_init(void)" (??1do_init@openssl_init_base@detail@ssl@asio@boost@@QAE@XZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ENGINE_cleanup referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::asio::ssl::detail::openssl_init_base::do_init::~do_init(void)" (??1do_init@openssl_init_base@detail@ssl@asio@boost@@QAE@XZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class boost::shared_ptr<class cql::cql_cluster_t> __thiscall cql::cql_builder_t::build(void)" (?build@cql_builder_t@cql@@QAE?AV?$shared_ptr@Vcql_cluster_t@cql@@@boost@@XZ) referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class cql::cql_builder_t & __thiscall cql::cql_builder_t::add_contact_point(class boost::asio::ip::address const &)" (?add_contact_point@cql_builder_t@cql@@QAEAAV12@ABVaddress@ip@asio@boost@@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>D:\dev\CassandraData\VisualStudio\Test_Boost\Debug\Test_Boost.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 19 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I am a complete newbie in cpp and I would appreciate any help!

Thank you!

Comment: Did you use cmake to create your Visual Studio project? If you did not do that.

Comment: Did you compile boost with openssl support?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357751/boost-ssl-with-visual-studio-2010-and-openssl